# Autocomplete multiple field values

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have limited experience with Jquery in general and this is the first time I have tried using the autocomplete. I have defined the ready event as per below (please note I have used a dummy url in my example).

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ELEMENTID").autocomplete({
    source: "example.asp",
    minLength: 3
    });
 });
```

If my example.asp returns a simple array: `["val1", "val2", val3"]`

this works well and the textbox with id "ELEMENTID" updates accordingly. I'm actually using this as a suburb/postcode/state validator. The user will be entering a suburb, and after making their selection I would like to also auto populate the postcode and suburb fields. How can I pass these extra values back in my example.asp, and

How do I then access them through the page that is making the call?

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{"label":"some_label", "value":"val1", "postcode": "some_postcode"},
 {"label":"some_label2", "value":"val2", "postcode": "some_postcode2"},
 {"label":"some_label3", "value":"val3", "postcode": "some_postcode3"}]
```

and set the appriopriate values by using [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ELEMENTID").autocomplete({
        source: "example.asp",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#id_postcode').val(ui.item.postcode);
        }
    });
});
```